# Remove Email Address from "To" field

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to reply all from my group's Outlook public folder but remove the public folder email address from the reply addresses.

So far the code I have is:

```
Sub Reply_All_From_Folder()

    Dim original As MailItem

    Dim reply As MailItem

    Set original = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll

    Set reply = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With reply

        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "folder@work.com"

        .Subject = original.Subject

        .To = original.To

        .CC = original.CC

        .HTMLBody = original.HTMLBody

        .Recipients.ResolveAll

        .Display

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Rolled back as you edited the solution into the question. That removes the Q part of the Q & A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The To and CC fields are semicolon-delimited String lists. For removing the address, you need to replace it with empty string `""`

replace your

```
.To = original.To
```

with

```
.To = Replace(original.To, "emailoRemove@test.com", "")
```

MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. Outlook is just formatting the public folder email in various ways(with/without spaces and with/without the domain) but I got that working.

Now I am just trying to figure out how to close the "original email". I tried  "original.close olsave" and it remains open.

Comment: When resolve all cannot process (due to multiple users on our system with the same first/last name) the macro fails to run. Is there a way to get outlook to display the names and let me select which john doe I want (if not then maybe just remove the names it can't resolve)

Comment: @jnjustice I suggest you to post this problem as a separate question.